# Neo4j cypher query failing with "Don't know how to compare that"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple test graph that I run this query on:

```
MATCH p = (l)-[*1..1]->(start)-[*3..3]->(r) where id(start) = 1101 return l,r
```

This used to work in Neo4j 2.1, but after upgrading to 2.2, it no longer does, giving this error:

```
Don't know how to compare that. Left: [:has_participant[1027]{}] ($colon$colon); Right: :sampled[1025]{} (RelationshipProxy)
```

This query works:

```
MATCH p = (l)-[*1..1]->(start)-[*1..1]->(r) where id(start) = 1101 return l,start,r
```

Resulting in this visualisation:

[image]

The left node is (l), John node is (start) and the green nodes are (r).

If I double click on the green nodes, and then double-click on the nodes that appear, I can get to my intended (r) nodes, which are labelled as lanes:

[image]

Each "level" in this tree is joined with different relationships; 'has_participants' connects (l) to (start), and 'sampled' connects (start) to the green nodes. 'prepared' connects green to blue, and 'sequenced' connects blue to pink.

Given (start), how do I get to (l) and the 2 pink Lane nodes shown above without encountering the error? What I'm actually trying to do is a generic "give me descendant nodes of (start) that are at least 3 steps away", so I can't use knowledge of the sampled->prepared->sequenced relationship path.

Here's the result of EXPLAIN on the problem query:

[image]

This variant on the query works:

```
MATCH p = (l)-->(start)-[*3..3]->(r) where id(start) = 1101 return l,r
```

But why has my original query stopped working? What if I wanted to do 2..2 on the left?

Edit: in fact, even stranger is that these work:

```
MATCH p = (l)-[*0..1]->(start)-[*3..3]->(r) where id(start) = 1101 return l,r
MATCH p = (l)-[*1..2]->(start)-[*3..3]->(r) where id(start) = 1101 return l,r
```

Only 1..1 on the left fails.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using id() functions for querying - they can change.

What happens if you do

MATCH p = (l)-[*1..1]->(start {name:"John"})-[*3..3]->(r) return l,r

You probably want to put an index on the "start" node's label/property.

Comment: An earlier query I would have ran first found John by indexed properties. Now I have a John node and am trying to find out things about it, such as what is it's parent, and what are its descendants 3 steps away. In any case, your version results in the same error.

Comment: Where do the "problematic" [:has_relationship] and [:sampled] relationships sit? in the [*1..1] or in the [*3..3]? Have you tried putting EXPLAIN before the query? Have you tried replacing [*1..1] by just -- ?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, has_relationship is on the left in the 1..1, and sampled is on the right and is the first step of ..3. I'll add the results of explain to the question. With 1..1 replaced with -- it works.

Comment: I added some extra variants of the command that work to the end of the question. Is this a bug that 1..1 doesn't work?

Comment: Well 1..1 is a bit of a strange statement, isn't it? You are looking for *directly connected* nodes, with rels of whatever reltype, and the proper cypher syntax for that has always been -- afaik... It does not really make sense to formulate "directly connected" (which is what -- means) nodes as "variable length paths with path length between 1 and 1" (which is what 1..1 means). It may have been permitted in the past - I don't know. But it makes sense to me like this.

Comment: BTW: the reason this probably no longer works is because you are using the Cypher Cost Based Planner as from 2.2. You can probably still get this to work with the "old" rule-based planner. See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-are-queries-executed.html on how to do that.